# How to correctly use Observable data, to modify this data with other Observable and to return it as Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have angular2 project and in it I have this class:

```
class Application {
    id: number;
    last_android_releasse_url: string;
    last_android_releasse: Release;
    last_ios_releasse_url: string;
    last_ios_releasse: Release;
}
```

I fetch all applications and load them with the | async pipe this way:

```
this.asyncApps = this.appService.getAll(this.params)
      .do((data: any) => {
        this.count = data.count;
      }).map(data => {
        return data.apps;
      });
```

What I need is to load every release object for every app inside the data.apps and to return observable for the asyncApps to work with the async pipe. I wasn't sure how to ask my question so I accept proposals for title change. 
So the final code should do something like this:

```
this.asyncApps = this.appService.getAll(this.params)
      .do((data: any) => {
        this.count = data.count;
      }).map(data => {
        for (let app of data.apps) {
          this.http.get(app.last_android_releasse_url).subscribe(
            release_data => {
              app.last_android_releasse = release_data.json().last_android_releasse;
            },
            error => this.alertService.showError(error.etext)
          );
          this.http.get(app.last_ios_releasse_url).subscribe(
            release_data => {
              app.last_ios_releasse = release_data.json().last_ios_releasse;
            },
            error => this.alertService.showError(error.etext)
          );
        }
        return data.apps;
      });
```

And this one works, but I was thinking about something with flatMap or forkJoin. Just doesn't seem like the right solution to me. Could you help me clear that please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you can use flatMap . Thanks for asking , here is what I attempted.

```
this.asyncApps = this.appService.getAll(this.params)
      .do((data: any) => {
        this.count = data.count;
      })
      .flatMap(data => Observable.from(data.apps))
      .flatMap(app => Observable.forkJoin(
            this.http.get(app.last_android_releasse_url).map(d => d.json().last_android_releasse),
            this.http.get(app.last_ios_releasse_url).map(d=>d.json().last_ios_releasse))
          .first()
          .map(res => Object.assign(app, {
                  last_android_releasse : res[0],
                  last_ios_releasse : res[1]})
           )
      );
```

Let me know if its working.

---

Here is what I did

```
this.asyncApps = this.appService.getAll(this.params)
```

Perform network call

```
          .do((data: any) => {
            this.count = data.count;
          })
```

Update count to number of result

```
          .flatMap(data => Observable.from(data.apps))
```

Convert stream of list to stream of individual items

```
          .flatMap(app => Observable.forkJoin(
```

For each app , am converting app without response to app with response data. As its asynchronous and needs Observable, used flatMap.

```
                this.http.get(app.last_android_releasse_url).map(d => d.json().last_android_releasse),
                this.http.get(app.last_ios_releasse_url).map(d=>d.json().last_ios_releasse))
```

Do separate calls in parallel and combine the result in stream of array

```
              .first()
```

Get the first result

```
              .map(res => Object.assign(app, {
                      last_android_releasse : res[0],
                      last_ios_releasse : res[1]})
               )
```

convert the result to app with result

```
          );
```

Finally we should have a stream of apps with response in each of them.

Comment: Yes. This answer helped me a lot. The only problem was that at the end should return array (or async), so I added .toArray(). I did try to use scan() as well. I want to return the result right after the application releases are added, without waiting for all other application releases to be returned, but scan returned the result unordered. Also I don't understand why we need to use .first(), because this observable returns only one result. So using .toArray() works but then comes the problem, that the page is loaded if all applications and their releases are returned. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Without .toArray() or .scan() the compile time error is : Type 'Observable<Application>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Application[]>'. So seems that the observable returns one application at a time.